# How to access the remote database using java

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection

Iam trying to access database from system to other system, below is code.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class testConnection {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws SQLException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:1433;DatabaseName=fingerprintdb;user=sa;password=test"; 
        // Change the connection string according to your db, ip, username and password 
          Connection con = null;
        try { 

            // Load the Driver class. 
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"); 
            // If you are using any other database then load the right driver here. 

            //Create the connection using the static getConnection method 
             con = DriverManager.getConnection (connectionURL); 

            //Create a Statement class to execute the SQL statement 
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement(); 

            //Execute the SQL statement and get the results in a Resultset 
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select moviename, releasedate from movies"); 

            // Iterate through the ResultSet, displaying two values 
            // for each row using the getString method 

            while (rs.next()) 
                System.out.println("Name= " + rs.getString("moviename") + " Date= " + rs.getString("releasedate")); 
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
        finally { 
            // Close the connection 
            con.close(); 
        } 

    }

}
```

Below is exception iam getting.

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host xxx.xxx.xx.xx, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:170)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1049)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:833)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:716)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:841)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at testConnection.main(testConnection.java:26)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at testConnection.main(testConnection.java:48)
```

Iam able to connect to the database from the same syste. but now iam trying to connect remote way.

I got the above ip address from typing ipconfig in cmd prompt.
Am I doing correctly, if not please correct me.

Below is log of pings to host.

```
Pinging xxx.xxx.xx.xx with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from xxx.xxx.xx.xx: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from xxx.xxx.xx.xx: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from xxx.xxx.xx.xx: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from xxx.xxx.xx.xx: TTL expired in transit.

Ping statistics for xxx.xxx.xx.xx:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Comment: thanks for updating. Have you tried to open telnet connection on that port(1433)? just to check specific port is open or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Sometimes it Happens.. **(Do the following Process where your SQLServer is installed)**

You need to Go to

`Start > Microsoft SQL Server > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager`

When it opens Go to

```
SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for SQLExpress
```

Where you'll find the Protocol TCP/IP, if disabled then Enable it Click on TCP/IP, You'll find its properties.

In this properties Remove All the TCP Dynamic Ports and Add value of 1433 to all TCP Port
and restart your

```
SQL Server Services > SQL Server
```

And Its Done...

Comment: i will try your suggestions and will let you know the status

Comment: I have done exactly what you suggested, but still iam getting same exception

Comment: have you changed all of your TCP Dynamic Ports to 1433?

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure the remote SQL server to accept TCP/IP connection and you may require to  allow remote connection in case if it not enabled.